# Creating an exception when pointing a domain using A record (Shopify)

Tags: .htaccess, dns, shopify, domain-name, a-records

I am setting up a Shopify site using a custom domain.  However, I have old links on that domain that I don't want to break once I point it to Shopify.  I also have old parked domains on top of this domain that I don't want to break.

Shopify [instructs you](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/settings/domains/third-party-domains/popular-providers/godaddy) to set up an A record for the domain (so when I go to www.mydomain.com I see my Shopify store).  But I want to set up exceptions such that www.mydomain.com/my-seo-link won't show Shopify, or will allow me to forward to its replacement at Shopify.

An added complication is I also have parked domains on top of my domain that I want to remain pointing to my old server.

Is there such thing as a URI exception to an A record?

Comment: So what URL should `www.mydomain.com/my-seo-link` be redirected to?

Comment: Ideally it would stay on the same URL but be running off of my server instead of Shopify's.  Alternatively I could set up a separate domain on my server and forward it there.

Comment: Alternate thing can be done but it will change the URL in the browser

Comment: That's ok.  What does that solution look like?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file of `www.mydomain.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^my-seo-link http://otherdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Will that work even if mydomain.com has an A record pointing to another IP address?

Comment: @anubhava Won't tr break when mydomain.com CNAMEing points to mystore.myshopify.com?

Answer (score 0):

Go through your list of special URL's and use the Shopify built-in redirect mechanism to point all your old content at the new location for it on your Shopify store's domain. The DNS system is old, well understood and you need to use it in this case as you cannot have a Shopify store on a domain AND host that same domain on another server under your control. Use redirects. That is what they are they for.