# Can I add an A record for Shopify while redirecting particular urls?

Tags: redirect, dns, shopify

I need to add an A record to my domain to point to Shopify.

Shopify lets you redirect URLs, but not for certain paths (e.g. '/cart').

I need to redirect my old urls containing this path ('cart') for SEO.

Is there any way, using DNS records, to set the A record for Shopify while redirecting certain urls? Note: I can't use .htaccess

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24540168/creating-an-exception-when-pointing-a-domain-using-a-record-shopify) is similar, however, none of the answers are relevant because (a) I need to redirect using an excluded path, and (b)I can't use .htaccess once the A record is in place, as the request will not be sent to my server, but Shopifys.

Comment: is it that important to redirect the ../cart when you will be redirecting your full legacy domain to Shopify?

Comment: alexandresaiz - Thanks for your question. I would say it's important because if I can't redirect certain URLS containing /cart - for example, /cart/add/my-product-page-here - I will loose all the social stats from Facebook etc, and, even if only temporarily, the SEO goodness.

Comment: You don't need the cart url to be available for either google bot or any social link s the cart url at shopify is dynamic so it will never have the same content. I would suggest forcing the web bots not to crawl your cart page at all!

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. The new site is on Shopify. The cart url I want to redirect is from the old site, and it isn't dynamic. It isn't really a cart page, it just has 'cart' in the url. Unfortunately this is the url that has accumulated Facebook likes, etc. Those social stats will be lost, thus my question :-)

Comment: post the original urls and where do you want each one to point to so that we can try to help